# Get data of 3rd table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 3 table : events,students and parent_student_relation.

**events**

```
id | class_id | title
----------------------
1  | 16       | ABC
2  | 17       | JKL
3  | 18       | XYZ
```

**students**

```
id | class_id | name
----------------------
5  | 18       | StudentName1
6  | 17       | StudentName2
7  | 16       | StudentName3
```

**parent_student_relation**

```
student_id | parent_id
----------------------
        4  | 10
        5  | 10
        6  | 11
        7  | 11
```

Now i want to get data from `events` where i pass `parent_id = 10` then get following output.

**Output**

```
id | class_id | title
----------------------
3  | 18       | XYZ
```

And i pass `parent_id = 11` then get following output.

**Output**

```
id | class_id | title
----------------------
1  | 16       | ABC
2  | 17       | JKL
```

I tried with following code :

```
$q_student = "SELECT student_id FROM parent_student_relation WHERE parent_id = " . $parent_id;

$q_class = "SELECT class_id FROM students WHERE id IN($q_student) GROUP BY class_id";

$q = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE class_id IN($q_class)";
```

So i can get perfect output in `$query = mysql_query($q);`

But I want to all in only one join query. So how can do it?? Or its possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query="SELECT * 
  FROM parent_student_relation AS a 
  JOIN students AS b 
  ON a.student_id = b.id 
  JOIN events AS c 
  ON b.class_id = c.class_id 
  WHERE a.parent_id = " . $parent_id;
```

Comment: or change to SELECT c.* to * and you will see all data

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$query="select e.id,e.class_id,e.title,s.id from event e 
           inner join student s on e.class_id=s.class_id
           inner join parent_student_relation p on s.id=p.student_id
            where p.parent_id=$parent_id";
```